# Can't bind to 'children' since it isn't a known property of 'ul' in Angular14

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am using Angular14.
I'm trying to recursive data array multidimensional in accordion bootstrap content.
but doesn't work,

```
Error Code : ngtsc(-998002)

Message  : Can't bind to 'children' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'.

Error in :  `[children]="subitems.children" [parent]="self"`
```

My code :

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: '[recursive]',
  template: `<li *ngFor="let items of treeNodes">
                <div class="accordion-item" >
                    <div class="accordion-header">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#Accor_'+items.id" aria-expanded="true" >
                        <input class="form-check-input chkAll me-2" type="checkbox" value="">{{items.name}}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div [attr.id]="'Accor_'+items.id" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-body ms-3" *ngIf="items.children.length > 0">
                            <div class="row" *ngFor="let subitems of items.children">
                                <div *ngIf="subitems.children.length < 1" class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">{{subitems.name}}</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" value ="">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">OPEN</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" value="">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">OPEN</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <ul recursive *ngIf="subitems.children.length > 1" [children]="subitems.children" [parent]="self" ></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>`,
})
export class ModuleItemComponent  {
    @Input() children: any;
    @Input() parent: any;  
    self=this;
}
```

But, when i another recursive array menu  it's working. like this

```
 @Component({
      selector: '[recursive]',
      template: `
      <li *ngFor="let item of children" [ngClass]="{'nav-item dropdown': item.children.length > 0}" >
        <a *ngIf="item.children.length > 0 && item.url == null " href="javascript:void(0);" [ngClass]="item.lvl > 1 ? 'nav-link dropdown-toggle lvl-submenu': 'nav-link dropdown-toggle'"
         data-bs-auto-close="outside"  data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{item.name}} </a>
        <a *ngIf="item.url != null" routerLink="/{{item.url}}" [ngClass]="item.lvl > 1 ? 'dropdown-item': 'nav-link'">{{item.name}} </a>
        <ul recursive *ngIf="item.children.length > 0" [children]="item.children" [parent]="self" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
          [ngClass]="item.lvl > 1 ? 'submenu dropdown-menu': 'dropdown-menu'">
        </ul>
      </li>`,
    })
    
    export class MenuItemComponent  {
      
      @Input() children: any;
      @Input() parent: any;  
      self=this;
    }
```

why my code error.
Can anyone help me..
Thanks all
sorry my English is bad.

i want to recursive object array multiple tree

Comment: has you import the directive in the module you declare your component?